# How do I print a specific value of an array given a condition in jq if there is no key specified

Tags: json, kubernetes, select, jq

I am trying to output the value for .metadata.name followed by the student's name in .spec.template.spec.containers[].students[] array using the regex test() function in jq.

I am having trouble to retrieve the individual array value since there is no key specified for the students[] array.

For example, if I check the students[] array if it contains the word "Jeff", I would like the output to display as below:

```
student-deployment:    Jefferson
```

**What i have tried:**

I've tried the command below which somewhat works but I am not sure how to get only the "Jefferson" value. The command below would print out all of the students[] array values which is not what I want. I am using Powershell to run the command below.

```
kubectl get deployments -o json | jq -r '.items[] | select(.spec.template.spec.containers[].students[]?|test("\"^Jeff.\"")) | .metadata.name, "\":\t\"", .spec.template.spec.containers[].students'
```

Is there a way to print a specific value of an array given a condition in jq if there is no key specified? Also, would the solution work if there are multiple deployments?

The deployment template below is in json and I shortened it to only the relevant parts.

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "items": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
            "kind": "Deployment",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "student-deployment",
                "namespace": "default"
            },
            "spec": {
                "template": {
                    "spec": {
                        "containers": [
                            {
                                "students": [
                                        "Alice",
                                        "Bob",
                                        "Peter",
                                        "Sally",
                                        "Jefferson"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this approch, we introduce a variable `$pattern`. You may set it with `--arg pattern` to your regex, e.g. `"Jeff"` or `"^Al"` or `"e$"` to have the student list filtered by `test`, or leave it empty to see all students.

Now, we iterate over all `.item[]` elements (i.e. over "all deployments"). For each found, we output the content of `.metadata.name` followed by a literal colon and a space. Then we iterate again over all `.spec.template.spec.containers[].students[]`, perform the pattern `test` and concatenate the outcome.

To print out raw strings instead of JSON, we use the `-r` option when calling `jq`.

```
kubectl get deployments -o json \
| jq --arg pattern "Jeff" -r '
    .items[]
    | .metadata.name + ": " + (
        .spec.template.spec.containers[].students[]
        | select(test($pattern))
      )
  '
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked fine.

May I know if the same could be achieved using JsonPath query as well? For my JsonPath query, I've tried the query below:

`kubectl get deployment -o=jsonpath="{range .items[?(@.spec.template.spec.containers[*].students[*])]}{'\n'}{.metadata.name}{':\t'}{range .spec.template.spec.containers[*]}{.students[?(@=="Alice")]}{end}{end}"`

But this only works to evaluate for matching words. Would it be possible to use JsonPath to query for this as I've read that JsonPath regex =~ doesn't work?

Comment: @calmmash I'm sorry, I have absolutely no knowledge regarding kubernetes/kubectl and its options (Actually, in my answer I just replicated your call to it and had jq do the onward processing). Consider asking a new question focusing on that very issue in order to angle for the attention of kubernetes/kubectl experts.

Comment: Alright, no worries. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the "students" array(s) in the input, you could use this filter:

```
.items[]
| paths(objects) as $p
| getpath($p)
| select( objects | has("students") )
| .students
```

You can then add additional filters to select the particular student(s) of interest, e.g.

```
| .[]
| select(test("Jeff"))
```

And then add any postprocessing filters, e.g.

```
| "student-deployment: \(.)"
```

Of course you can obtain the `students` array in numerous other ways.